# не могу понять в чем ошибка, python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, pycharm, python-telegram-bot

```py
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext 

TOKEN = 'токен'
schedule = {}

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Привет! Я твой бот-дневник. Чтобы добавить расписание, используй команду /set_schedule.')

def set_schedule(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    if user_id != 868688202:
        update.message.reply_text('У вас нет прав для изменения расписания.')
        return
    text = update.message.text.replace('/set_schedule ', '')
    schedule[user_id] = text
    update.message.reply_text('Расписание установлено!')


def get_schedule(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    day = update.message.text.lower()
    if user_id in schedule:
        update.message.reply_text(f'Расписание на {day.capitalize()}: {schedule[user_id]}')
    else:
        update.message.reply_text('Расписание не установлено. Используй команду /set_schedule, чтобы установить расписание.')


def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("set_schedule", set_schedule))
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text & ~filters.command, get_schedule))
    updater.start_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

как результат я получаю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GadzhievAdil\Desktop\school-bot\main.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\GadzhievAdil\Desktop\school-bot\main.py", line 36, in main
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text & ~filters.command, get_schedule))
AttributeError: module 'telegram.ext.filters' has no attribute 'text'
```

использую python-telegram-bot v.13.3 (знаю, что старая, но так надо)

Comment: Ну там написано, что у `filters` нет аттрибута `text`. Попробуйте сделать перед этим `print(dir(filters))` и посмотреть - что же там есть в нём.

Answer (score 1):

В версии python-telegram-bot 13.3, фильтры теперь имеют немного другой синтаксис. Вместо
filters.text, вы должны использовать MessageTextFilter().

```
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, filters
# ...

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("set_schedule", set_schedule))
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters & ~filters.COMMAND & filters.TEXT, get_schedule))
    updater.start_polling()

# ...
```